# numpy.core.multiarray failed to import after installing asammdf package

Tags: python, numpy, asammdf

I try to read the mf4 file which has acoustic signal.

```
from asammdf import MDF
data = MDF('file1.mf4')
```

The packages that I installed are

asammdf    7.0.7

numpy      1.22.3

```
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath: The specified module could not be found.

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\susan\Anaconda3\envs\env1\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py", line 356, in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File "c:\users\susan\testdatfile.py", line 10, in <module>
    from asammdf import MDF

  File "C:\Users\susan\Anaconda3\envs\env1\lib\site-packages\asammdf\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .blocks.source_utils import Source

  File "C:\Users\susan\Anaconda3\envs\env1\lib\site-packages\asammdf\blocks\source_utils.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import v2_v3_blocks as v3b

  File "C:\Users\susan\Anaconda3\envs\env1\lib\site-packages\asammdf\blocks\v2_v3_blocks.py", line 16, in <module>
    from numexpr import evaluate

  File "C:\Users\susan\Anaconda3\envs\env1\lib\site-packages\numexpr\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from numexpr.interpreter import MAX_THREADS, use_vml, __BLOCK_SIZE1__

ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

I already checked the numpy version  `pip install -U numpy`
It said `Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\susan\anaconda3\envs\env1\lib\site-packages (1.22.3)`

May I know how can I solve this issue?
Thank you.

Comment: Are running vanilla Python or some distribution?

Answer (score 1):

Installing Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable could help

Answer (score 0):

Are running vanilla Python or some distribution?